# How to just type English in input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need just English type in input, add function for this input:

```
function englishType() {
    $('input[lang^=en]').keypress(function(event){
        var ew = event.which;
        if(ew == 32)
            return true;
        if(48 <= ew && ew <= 57)
            return true;
        if(65 <= ew && ew <= 90)
            return true;
        if(97 <= ew && ew <= 122)
            return true;
        alert("error");
        return false;
    });
}
```

But user can copy `تست` (any word in other language) and paste on this input and not work this code!

.keypress not work for `Copy and Paste`.

How can I fix?

Comment: Don't be so blasé about which characters you accept. I'm getting a déjà vu of the problems you're facing. If you think that's all the characters you need then you're unfortunately quite naïve.

Comment: Hi @NiettheDarkAbsol, No! I need just type English to input. User can Copy and Paste other keyword in input. and not work this code. How can i isse?

Comment: Does this input field exist in a form? If so you can use jQuery validation to validate that form.@mySun

Comment: Hi @GayathriMohan, user can copy (any word in other language) and paste on this input and not work this code!

Comment: You know English uses other letters right? @NiettheDarkabsol gave you examples of several English (borrowed) words you won't allow.

Comment: You are approaching the situation wrong. Try validating the value, not restricting it.

Comment: What everyone here is trying to suggest is that not allowing particular characters is the wrong approach here and ultimately creates bad user experience. Perhaps you should allow any input and decide server side how to use/sanitize it so it doesn't break your code. If your request is to only allow English words, you should probably be using a library with all the English words. Limiting letters won't get you very far and its (most likely) a bad approach.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to use the `keyup` event and not the `keypress`.

Second, if you want the users to prevent pasting non-English characters, you would need to process all of the `event.target.value` to weed out characters that you don't want, or raise an error, whatever the case be. You can use regex for that; range `[a-zA-Z ]` should work fine. You can augment this with other characters that you are willing to allow.

```
event.target.value.match( /[^a-zA-Z ]/ ) // Array if value outside the range
```

Third, like the other comments say, you are limiting a lot of English words, like `Résumé` for example, so this is not necessarily a good idea. But, your use case may be different.

Comment: Hi `keyup` event not good, because `backspace` is run `keyup` event

Comment: **All keys fire the `keyup` event.** Plus, in case of user pasting the text, restricting based on `event.keyCode` is not going to help because the charCode will be of the Control key or 17, and you would have basically disabled the user to even use Ctrl+A or any other combination.